# I want to create a .NET 7 and Angular 16 authentication and role-based authorisation (admin/customer) for example

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jwt, authorization, roles

I wrote the code of the API, but I don't know how it is linked with the Angular project.

This is the middleware configuraton in the `program.cs` file:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthService, AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
{})
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabContext>();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})

// Adding Jwt Bearer  
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Secret"]))
                };
            });
```

This is the auth service file :

```
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly DatabContext databContext;

    public AuthService(UserManager<User> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IConfiguration configuration, DatabContext databContext)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.roleManager = roleManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
        this.databContext = databContext;
    }

    public async Task<(int, string)> Registration(RegistrationModel model)
    {
        var userExists = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.username);

        if (userExists != null)
            return (0, "User already exists");

        var user = new User()
            {
                Email = model.mail,
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                UserName = model.username,
                Token="Null"
            };

        var createUserResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.password);

        if (!createUserResult.Succeeded)
            return (0, "User creation failed! Please check user details and try again.");

        if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Comptable))
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.Comptable));

        if (await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Comptable))
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Comptable);

        databContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return (1, "User created successfully!");
    }

    public async Task<(int, string)> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

        if (user == null)
            return (0, "Invalid username");

        if (!await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
            return (0, "Invalid password");

        var userRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        var authClaims = new List<Claim>
        {
           new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
           new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        };

        foreach (var userRole in userRoles)
        {
            authClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userRole));
        }

        string token = GenerateToken(authClaims);

        return (1, token);
    }

    private string GenerateToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        var authSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:Secret"]));

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Issuer = _configuration["JWT:ValidIssuer"],
                Audience = _configuration["JWT:ValidAudience"],
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(authSigningKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims)
            };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
    }
}
```

I want to know how to send the JWT and how to handle it to use it in the front end to handle component authorisation.

I didn't try anything because I don't know how to use guards and routers